# Delete Rows based on Selected Cells in a Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create a macro that does, among other things, deletes the rows in a table where column J is blank. Column J is not truly blank though, it is blank because a formula set resulted in a blank (the formula is below for reference).

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[orig_site]],SITE_CLEAN,2,FALSE),"")
```

I have gotten to the point where I am copying column J, pasting the values in over the formula, using text to column to make the blank cells truly blank, selecting blank cells in column J, then trying to Selection.EntireTow.Delete but I keep getting an error that reads "Run-time error '1004': Delete method of Range class failed"

```
Range("OpenCycle_DATA[SITE_CLEAN]").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("J2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("OpenCycle_DATA[SITE_CLEAN]").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: You have the range "OpenCycle_DATA[SITE_CLEAN]" and you want to delete every row where the value in column J is "" whether by value or by formula. This code is just a workaround, because SpecialCells doesn't treat cells with formulas as blanks. If this is true, then there are other methods to achieve this task. Please confirm, so I can create a working solution.

Comment: use the autofilter method to filter on rows where value = "" in `ListObjects("OpenCycle_DATA").ListColumns("SITE_CLEAN")`, then use `xlCellTypeVisible` from SpecialCells to delete those rows.